# How can I avoid infinite loops in my React Router private routes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, axios, react-router-dom, router

In my App.js, I have some authenticated pages I protect with `<PrivateRoute>`, like so:

```
<PrivateRoute path="/dashboard">
  <Dashboard />
</PrivateRoute>
```

I implement `<PrivateRoute>` like so:

```
function PrivateRoute({ children, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route {...rest} render={() => <CheckRedirect children={children} />} />
  );
}
```

The problem is, the `<CheckRedirect>` function calls out to an endpoint on my server which **dynamically tells you where to redirect**.

Here's the function:

```
export const CheckRedirect = ({ children }) => {
  const [isChecking, setIsChecking] = React.useState(true);
  const [target, setTarget] = React.useState(null);

  const url = "https://example.com/get-redirect"

  useEffect(() =>{
    async function getPage() {
      axios.get(url)
      .then(function (response) {
        setTarget(response.data.message)
      }).finally(() => setIsChecking(false))
    }
    
    getPage();  
  }, []);

  if (isChecking) {
    return "... Checking";
  }

  return {target} ? (
    <Redirect to={target} />
  ) : (
    <Redirect to='/404' />
  );
};
```

If you're not logged in, it will send back "/login" in the `message` field. If you're logged in, it will send "/dashboard".

If it sends back "/dashboard", then React Router *produces an infinite loop!* It tries the same `<PrivateRoute>` again, which calls out to the endpoint again, which will once again return "/dashboard", and so on...

Is there a way I can tell my `<PrivateRoute>` to *not* do the `<CheckRedirect>` function if this is already the result of a redirect?

Comment: I'm fairly sure you should be able to send the current route name from `PrivateRoute` to your `CheckRedirect` function and only do the `setTarget ` in your `getPage` fetch if it returns a different route.

Comment: @benomatis Could you show me an example? If I don't do `setTarget`, then it would return the `<Redirect to='/404' />` part of the switch statement at the bottom.

I need PrivateRoute to somehow never call the `CheckRedirect` function

Answer (score 1):

Just change your PrivateRoute Logic to something like this

```
            const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
               
               return (
                  <Route
                     {...rest}

                     render = { props =>

                        user.isOnline ? ( <Component {...props} /> ) :
                        ( 
                           <Redirect
                              to={{
                                 pathname: "/login",
                                 state: { from: props.location }
                              }}
                           />
                        )
                     }
                  />
               )
            }
```

then

```
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it myself, but have you tried passing `path` as a prop to `CheckRedirect` and only do the `setTarget` in your `getPage` fetch if it returns a different route?

```
function PrivateRoute({ children, path, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route {...rest} render={() => <CheckRedirect children={children} path={path} />} />
  );
}
```

```
export const CheckRedirect = ({ children, path }) => {
  const [isChecking, setIsChecking] = React.useState(true);
  const [target, setTarget] = React.useState(null);

  const url = "https://example.com/get-redirect"

  useEffect(() =>{
    async function getPage() {
      axios.get(url)
      .then(function (response) {
        const newPath = response.data.message
        if (path !== newPath) {
          setTarget(newPath)
        }
      }).finally(() => setIsChecking(false))
    }
    
    getPage();  
  }, []);

  if (isChecking) {
    return "... Checking";
  }

  return {target} ? (
    <Redirect to={target} />
  ) : (
    <Redirect to='/404' />
  );
};
```

To avoid `CheckRedirect` to do any redirect if everything is ok (ie. it's a valid request for that route), ensure `CheckRedirect` actually returns `null` in that case. If you have control over the server response, I'd return a different value (not `null`, but `-1` for example) for non-existent routes (ie. to redirect to 404), and keep `null` for when you really just want to return `null`.

Comment: If I don't call `setTarget`, the function will return the `<Redirect to='/404' />` line at the bottom. I think what we need is for `PrivateRoute` to *never call* the `CheckRedirect` function

Comment: you should be able to just return null, that should work, I think... I'll update my answer

Comment: Or perhaps `{children}`?

Comment: Do you have control on the response given back from the server? If you do, then I'd just change the return statement there and ensure it returned something specific to trigger 404, ie. `-1` instead of `null`, and keep `null` to return just `null` in case you don't want a redirect... would returning `null` (just plain `null` without the `<Redirect>` component) in `CheckRedirect` work at all, can you try?

Comment: returning `null` just redirects me back to the homepage `/` instead of rendering the Dashboard component. I'm not sure why. I don't think the server response is the issue here, just how we're handling on the client side.

Comment: do you think I should be using `children` somehow?

Comment: `children` would return whatever component you set inside `PrivateRoute`, but it wouldn't prevent a redirect if by doing `CheckRedirect` you always fetch, and always redirect if it has a result other than null (or any other nullish value, for that matter), so the only way you can stop that loop is if you only do the redirect on condition, and otherwise stop the redirect. When you say `returning null just redirects me back to the homepage /`, do you mean you just do `return target` without allowing `setTarget` to kick in?

Comment: ...I mean, if you just `return null` (or `return {target}` but never do `setTarget`) inside `CheckRedirect`, will it just redirect to the home page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231864/discussion-between-alwaysquestioning-and-benomatis).

Answer (score 0):

In `CheckRedirect` component, you don't even use children prop. It renders a string and then redirects to a page. It's normal that it loops forever. Pass `path` as a prop to `CheckRedirect` component and if it's same as server response, render the children.

Add path prop and pass it:

```
  export const CheckRedirect = ({ children, path }) => {
```

Add your conditional before redirecting:

```
  if (target === path) {
    return children
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not address the case where I have a *different* PrivateRoute, like so:

`<PrivateRoute path="/account">
<OtherComponent>
</PrivateRoute>`

Comment: If the user were to go to `/account`, and then the CheckRedirect function returned `/dashboard`, then the infinite loop happens again (because `path` is not equal to `target` in that case)